# Is the .iso file the one I need to download?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, virtualization

I want to install Linux Ubuntu for Virtual Box, but is the .iso file the correct one for it, or will it just set up as another base operating system directly?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You install Ubuntu the same way in a VM as you do on real hardware. Connect the iso to your VM as virtual CD/DVD drive, boot the VM from it and let the installer do its job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the `.iso` file.

I'll assume you've installed [Oracle VM VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). You then need to create a new VirtualBox - follow the wizard checking each step carefully. Give it at least 10GB of HDD space.

When it's created, click Settings and then Storage, click the "Empty" with the CD icon and click the CD with a down arrow next to it. Browse to your ISO file.

Then start the VM and follow the install process.

Answer (score 0):

You may download a 32-bit or 64-bit iso, depending on your hardware support. Start VirtualBox and create a new VM...

- OS type: Linux
- Version: Ubuntu32 (or 64)

[This article](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/virtualbox) has a lot of advice for your situation.

Comment: Thank you, both answers were very helpful, I would accept both if I could, but I can just accept one